# Slax Linux: Save changes (persistent USB) after selecting copy to RAM at boot

Tags: live-usb, macintosh, persistence

**Explanation:**

Right now I'm using a MacBookPro9,2 with Slax. I'm on an exchange trip and I'm having problems with my main HD (either bad SATA cable or damaged SSD).

Repairing the hardware on my machine might be expensive/slow or even impossible until I go back home, that is July next year. I obviously need to work on my projects and I know my machine can run live sessions without any problems, I've tried it with Kali, Ubuntu, Mint, Puppy and Slax.

I'm really fond of the idea of copying the system to RAM in order to gain speed and prevent USB stick wear due to read/write operations.

My needs are really minimal: Using Octave, Python3, Node.js and perhaps some other tools.

I’ve chosen Slax because it’s a lightweight distro that allows me to install packages via apt.

**Question:**

Is there a way to save my config so that I don't have to reset the keyboard layout, download wifi drivers, Python3, Octave and Node each time I boot from the USB stick and copy everything to RAM?

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to edit /slax/boot/syslinux.cfg and in default menu entry, and at end of bottom line add `,toram` and then run ./bootinstall.sh again.

```
LABEL default
MENU LABEL Run Slax (Persistent changes)
KERNEL /slax/boot/vmlinuz
APPEND vga=normal initrd=/slax/boot/initrfs.img load_ramdisk=1 prompt_ramdisk=0 rw printk.time=0 consoleblank=0 slax.flags=perch,automount,toram
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using Puppy Linux instead of Slax. It boots to and runs from RAM then saves your changes at shutdown. Puppy doesn't provide a means for using APT directly but the tools you mention probably have .debs in Debian and/or Ubuntu repositories and Puppy has a tool to convert them to Puppy Pet Packages for installation. They may already be available in the Puppy Package Manager.